# Kubuntu Wily upgrade screen glitch

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, 15.10

I have upgraded to Wily and I am getting a weird screen glitch. I have uploaded the screen shot. Can somebody help me fix this? I have booted to Windows Vista and there are no glitches so I am ruling out hardware issue. Other windows managers too show the same glitch i.e. fluxbox, xfce etc. The graphics controller is an Intel 4 series with driver i915.

[Screen Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZJeu.png)

Comment: Proprietary or open source drivers?

Comment: I see garbled text too sometimes. Using intel gpu.

Comment: Open source drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Older Intel graphics adapters may need UXA acceleration instead of the default. The work-around is to change the Xorg acceleration method to UXA.

Edit (or create) as root or sudo a file named **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** as follows (there should be a tab before each line except the first and the last):

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Intel Graphics"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

Restart (reboot, restart your display manager, whatever). Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This  is  a   kernel bug.  Downgrading  to  the The  15.04 kernel   fixes  the  issue.

see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1509556